# Assigning lat long to CLLocation giving error not accepting any format

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, cllocation

I am giving lat long to CLLocation in this way.

```
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]init];
    loc.coordinate.latitude = [sLat floatValue];
    loc.coordinate.longitude = [sLng floatValue];
```

Coming from

```
 NSMutableDictionary *locat = [dictLoc valueForKey:@"location"];
sLat = [locat valueForKey:@"lat"];
sLng = [locat valueForKey:@"lng"];
```

Showing correct values in console, but kills when allocated to cllocation.
Please guide for the above.
Thanks.

Comment: what does "kills" mean?

Comment: where does "`dictLoc`" come from?  what is it?

Comment: Try `[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[sLat floatValue] longitude:[sLng floatValue]]`, it should work.

Comment: done already not working.

Comment: What's not working? Can you provide the error/exception messages you're having? If you're sure that the values retrieved from the dictionary are valid, then the problem you're having isn't related to this part of your code.

Comment: not giving error, that's why i am not getting what is wrong.

Comment: -[__NSArrayI floatValue]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa5bce00 this msg got byusing zombies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the value in `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object like bellow...

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = [sLat doubleValue];
location.longitude = [sLng doubleValue];
```

**OR** Also try to retain that string like bellow..

```
sLat = [locat valueForKey:@"lat"];
[sLat retain];
sLng = [locat valueForKey:@"lng"];
[sLng retain];
```

and then assign it to `CLLocation`

hope this helpful to you....

Comment: what you want exactly?? because you can also use the location with coordinate with CLLocationCoordinate2D object...

Comment: [__NSArrayI floatValue]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa5bce00 This is the msg i am getting don't know why.

Comment: My code is ok, it is working in another sample project but not in my existing, don't know why this error is comibng.

Comment: but, it wasn't your code that works , but the idea you gave of retaining that works, i missed that retained all other objects but string was left.

Comment: ok ok i know but i just stay other option of CLLocationCoordinate2D which may be useful to other and in option i post that code for retain.. :)